# Can anyone identify this chrysalis, egg sack, or whatever it is?

Tags: identification, insects

[image: Closeup1]Can anyone identify what kind of insect makes this egg sack or chrysalis or whatever it is?[image: egg sack or maybe pupa][image: Closeup2]

Comment: Please [edit] in a picture where it's in focus.

Comment: Sorry, this is the best picture I could get with the camera on my Mac.  I will have to use a better camera next time I find another of these.

Comment: Seems more like a cockroach egg. With that aperture and focus, I am not wuite sure.

Comment: I found two more of these and photographed them with my a6300 camera, but it was difficult to get a good focus because the camera has a zoom lens which doesn't focus up close.  I stood back a few feet and zoomed it in.  One of the photos got a reasonably good focus.  I then had to crop the photos with GIMP to get the file size small enough to upload here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an egg sack from a Praying Mantis.